# CSRF token doesn't work (yii2)

Tags: angularjs, yii2

I'm trying to pass CSRF token with async http request.

Yii2 server response:

> Bad Request (#400) Unable to verify your data submission.

Angular request:

```
$http.post(
    /web/api/search', 
    {
        '_csrf': yii.getCsrfToken(),
        'data': $scope.data
    }
).success(function(response) {
    console.log("Hello, World!");
});
```

CSRF meta tags enabled as well: `<?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>`.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this initialization code in Angular. This code run correctly CSRF validation:

```
var moduleName = 'app';
var app = angular.module(moduleName, []);

app.run( function run($http){
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
    $http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRF-Token'] = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content");
});
```

Comment: This one breaks with an error saying (Uncaught ReferenceError: $httpProvider is not defined). Do you know why?

Comment: Try to deleted `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';`.

Comment: To retrieve token use yii.getCsrfToken(), but yii\web\YiiAsset asset must be registered.
$http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRF-Token'] = yii.getCsrfToken();